# How to convert THREE.Geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry from Face3?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to convert/update THREE.Geometry calls to THREE.BufferGeometry when that geometry is constructed also using the deprecated THREE.Face3 calls which I can't find any tidy solution to

Source: https://github.com/juniorxsound/Depthkit.js/blob/master/README.md

```
DepthKit.geo = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (let y = 0; y < VERTS_TALL; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < VERTS_WIDE; x++) {
            DepthKit.geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0));
        }
    }
    for (let y = 0; y < VERTS_TALL - 1; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < VERTS_WIDE - 1; x++) {
            DepthKit.geo.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(
                    x + y * VERTS_WIDE,
                    x + (y + 1) * VERTS_WIDE,
                    (x + 1) + y * (VERTS_WIDE)
                ));
            DepthKit.geo.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(
                    x + 1 + y * VERTS_WIDE,
                    x + (y + 1) * VERTS_WIDE,
                    (x + 1) + (y + 1) * (VERTS_WIDE)
                ));
        }
    }
```

I can get as far as using the guidance [here](https://sbcode.net/threejs/geometry-to-buffergeometry/) to make an array of Vector3 as 'points' and set the points on the buffer geometry using that, but I can't get the faces between each point to be written in any similar method to that of THREE.Face3 above... Any ideas?

I'm not the [only person](https://github.com/juniorxsound/Depthkit.js/issues/21) stuck on this for well over a year